# Debugging RegularExpressionValidator control

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have an asp:regularexpressionvalidator with the following expression to validate a file upload.

```
\.{1}x?html?$
```

Expresso shows me that it works. The simple html test page below shows that it works, but in my application, loading an html file in the file input always triggers the validator?!?

Anyone have any ideas or tips on debugging the javascript of this control?

Thanks,
Sam

the control:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="validRegexHtmlOnly" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fileImportHTML" 
        ValidationExpression="\.{1}x?html?" ErrorMessage="The file must be an HTML document (.html, .htm, .xhtml)" Display="Dynamic" />
```

simple test page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
 var txt = document.getElementById("txtInput").value;
 alert(/\.{1}x?html?$/.test(txt));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" id="txtInput" />
<input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="click me" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the regex in a RegularExpressionValidator is supposed to match the whole string, not just the end (or the beginning, or whatever).  Try changing your regex to

```
.*\.x?html?
```

On a side note, the `{1}` wasn't doing anything useful, so I removed it.  It's not necessary to tell a regex to match *one* of something; that's the default behavior.  And `{1}` won't stop it from matching *more* than one of the thing it's attached to, either.  All it does is clutter up your regex.

Comment: I was just answering the question myself when your answer popped up :) I got it working with ^\S+?\.{1}x?html?$ but your works as well so you get the cigar!

Comment: I actually had to further modify the RegEx to check case (as the control doesn't have a case-insensitive option)... ^.*\.[xX]?[hH][tT][mM][lL]?$ is the final working RegEx, unless someone has a more efficient one :)

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you are getting whitespace on the end of the filename. Not quite sure how that would happen in a web page, but it's the only thing I can think of.